# PHP Getting Previous MySQL Query's ID For Next Queries, How?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple question about MySQL and PHP here. Let's say I have this PHP syntax :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin',35)");
```

on that Person table, there's a column named ID (Auto Increment). how to get Peter Griffin's ID after INSERT process is done without making another SELECT query?

or is it possible to do INSERT for 2 tables using single query? for example I want to INSERT Peter's address as well on Address table :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Address (City, State, Zip)
VALUES ('Cupertino', 'California', 35212)");
```

that's all..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$new_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Put that right after your `INSERT` query and it will give you the id.

I would't recommend trying to do two `INSERT`s in one, and the `mysql_insert_id()` method will make it simplest for you and your code.